How to revert to Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS from 24.10
i upgraded to Ubuntu Studio 24.10 from 24.04.1 LTS, i thought i did the right thing but since then the problems keep coming one after another.
First i struggled to redo many settings on my desktop, it broke all my settings.
Since then the system seems unstable, i lost the opportunity to install snaps and my home screen was broken, i can no longer play certain videos on Tor.
In short, i'm tired of trying to fix things and i would like to go back to version 24.04.1 which worked very well.
I came from Fedora and switching to Ubuntu seemed like a good thing because i had too many problems with Fedora to install certain software.
I was charmed by 24.04.1 but 24.10 has been a horror since ...
Thank you for your help, cordially, Raf.

Restore your backups, as Debian/Ubuntu upgrade tools are intentionally one-way via automatic script; and manual backwards (ie. package by package).  The expected way backwards is to just restore your data from backups

Hello and thanks for your answers,
I don't have a backup system.
I do my backups manually on my files and folders.
i think what i have left to do is to reinstall 24.04, and to redo all my software installations, i am a web developer and i have a lot of tools to re-install. I am a little disappointed by Ubuntu, i didn't think the update would break so many things.
It may have been a mistake on my part to come to Ubuntu after Fedora.
Thanks for your answers,
kind regards,
Raf.
